# Transform translation and e.pageX/e.pageY coordinates differ

Tags: css, canvas, mouseevent, css-transforms

When I apply a translation (transform: translate...) on a canvas and I check its position on the Chrome Windows with `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`, I get different values. The same applies to the width of the canvas, it is different with `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` than the actual width value in the canvas.

The Chrome Zoom is set to 100%.

Is it normal or is there something to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A zoom style was applied to a parent 'div'. Taking it into account solved my problems.